# .Net framework 4 SDK download URL?

Tags: .net

You used to be able to download a neatly packaged .Net framework SDK, which had the framework + developer tools (other than Visual Studio of course).  What's the equivalent for .Net 4?

The reason I ask is that I need to upgrade my build server to build .Net 4 code, and I don't want to install Visual Studio on it.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Should be this one I believe: [Microsoft Windows SDK for Windows 7 and .NET Framework 4](https://www.microsoft.com/en-US/Download/confirmation.aspx?id=8279)

If the link dies in the future, searching for the exact string "*Microsoft Windows SDK for Windows 7 and .NET Framework 4*" should get the new link.

Comment: I wonder if this link will work for Windows 10 too...

Comment: This link is now dead.

Comment: https://www.microsoft.com/en-US/Download/confirmation.aspx?id=8279